# Failing to load a data from GitHub to Rstudio

Tags: r, github

I'm new to coding in R. Check what I did here (during an online course in edx)

I'm trying to load raw data from GitHub and I don't know if I succeeded or not. If I have, what is the file name? It doesn't seem to be working when I try to calculate the mean/sapply etc. thank you so much for your help!

```
library(downloader) 

 url <-"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/genomicsclass/dagdata/master/inst/extdata/femaleMiceWeights.csv"

 filename <- "femaleMiceWeights.csv"
 
download(url, destfile=filename)

**trying URL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/genomicsclass/dagdata/master/inst/extdata/femaleMiceWeights.csv'
Content type 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' length 252 bytes
downloaded 252 bytes**
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to work with that data in R, it's easier to just use `read.csv`, which also works with URLs and loads the data frame directly into R without needing to download the file locally:

```
URL <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/genomicsclass/dagdata/master/inst/extdata/femaleMiceWeights.csv"

femaleMiceWeights <- read.csv(URL)

head(femaleMiceWeights)

#   Diet Bodyweight
# 1 chow      21.51
# 2 chow      28.14
# 3 chow      24.04
# 4 chow      23.45
# 5 chow      23.68
# 6 chow      19.79
```

Answer (score 2):

It's downloading OK, but you need to read the actual csv file.

```
library(downloader)
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/genomicsclass/dagdata/master/inst/extdata/femaleMiceWeights.csv"
filename <- "femaleMiceWeights.csv"
download(url, destfile=filename)
df = read.csv(filename,stringsAsFactors = F)
mean(df$Bodyweight)

#[1] 25.3
```